# Parse REXML Document, ignoring whitespace

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, rexml

Should REXML ignore identation or whitespacing?

I am debugging an issue with a [simple HTML to Markdown convertor](https://github.com/xijo/reverse-markdown/blob/master/reverse_markdown.rb). For some reason it fails on

```
<blockquote><p>foo</p></blockquote>
```

But not on

```
<blockquote>
  <p>foo</p>
</blockquote>
```

The reason is, that in the first case, `type.children.first.value` is not set, in the latter case it is.
The original code can be found at link above, but a condensed snipped to show the problem is below:

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

def parse_string(string)
  doc = Document.new("<root>\n"+string+"\n</root>")
  root = doc.root
  root.elements.each do |element|
    parse_element(element, :root)
  end
end

def parse_element(element, parent)
  @output = ''
  # ...
  @output << opening(element, parent)
  #...
end

def opening(type, parent)
  case type.name.to_sym
    #...
    when :blockquote
       # remove leading newline
      type.children.first.value = ""
      "> "
  end
end

#Parses just fine
puts parse_string("<blockquote>\n<p>foo</p>\n</blockquote>")

# Fails with undefined method `value=' for <p> ... </>:REXML::Element (NoMethodError)
puts parse_string("<blockquote><p>foo</p></blockquote>")
```

I am quite certain, this is due to some parameter that makes REXML require whitespacing and identation: why else would it parse the first XML different from the latter?

Can I force REXML to parse both the same? Or am I looking at a whole different kind of bug?

Comment: Show a code sample demonstrating the problem. Also, you probably should use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). It's a great XML/HTML parser that is rapidly becoming the defacto choice.

Comment: I have added a condensed example. And about Nokogiri: I prefer that one too. But this is a script not by me, and I would like to simply fix it, instead of rewriting it to use a different XML library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the option :ignore_whitespace_nodes=>:all to Document.new().

Comment: That does not solve the problem; Where in the docs is ` :ignore_whitespace_nodes` mentioned?

Comment: Worked for me (MRI 2.0.0-p481).